# reading an image as a binary file

Tags: c++, image, file, binaryfiles

I was reading about [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14086/Image-Classification-Using-File-Header-Information) project on codeproject. It reads images as a binary object and then checks the first 10 bytes of its header. I wrote the following code to run on Windows machine:

```
int main () {

  std::ifstream is ("warren.jpg", std::ifstream::binary);
  if (is) {
    // get length of file:
   // is.seekg (0, is.end);
    int length = 11;
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);

    char * buffer = new char [length];


    std::cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... "<<endl;
    char c='b';
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
        is>>c;
    cout<<c<<endl;  //this just prints b 10 times
    }

    // read data as a block:
    is.read (buffer,length-1);
    buffer[length-1]= '\0';

    if (is)
      std::cout << "all characters read successfully.";
    else
      std::cout << "error: only " << is.gcount() << " could be read";
    is.close();

    cout<<"data is "<<buffer<<endl;

    // ...buffer contains the entire file...

    delete[] buffer;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The output was:

```
Reading 11 characters...
b
b
b
b
b
b
b
b
b
b
b
error: only 0 could be readdata is
```

So, I know that the first line

> std::ifstream is ("warren.jpg", std::ifstream::binary);

was successful as the if clause was entered. But after that nothing is received as input. I know that as it is a binary input, formatted input like **is >> c**  should not be used. But I wrote this only when **is.read()** was unsuccessful.

Can anyone please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Reverse course and find out why `is.read()` was unsuccessful.

Comment: Don't you have to open the file with the both the `ios::binary | ios::in` flags

Comment: @KristerAndersson...that was a stupid mistake on my part...thanks

Comment: @avinash did that fix your problem??

Comment: @user1944429..yes, that did allow me to read but when I tried o print it, the output was garbage(perhaps because the read in value was binary and cout couldn't print it properly). But then, I used the memcmp() function used in the codeproject's code(of which link is in the question) and could correctly define the image type

Comment: @avinash - I added my comment as an answer so we can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to open your file with the both the `ios::binary | ios::in` flags:

```
std::ifstream ifs (L"c:\\james.rar", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
```